# Running command line commands in Emacs, and receiving their output

Tags: emacs, command-line, elisp, ascii, ascii-art

I want to run a set of command line commands in a loop within emacs, with the loop stopping when the user taps a key.

This is in order to see an ascii 'video' appear in Emacs, which stops when you press a key.

I thought it would be fun to have image-to-ascii bit of text as a comment (with the image coming from my mac's camera).

I use imagesnap to take the camera image, and jp2a to convert it to ascii. I think imagesnap is mac only. Here's the code I have so far:

```
(defun ascii-video-comment ()                                                          
    "Makes video comment, requires imagemagick, jp2a, imagesnap"                        
    (interactive)                                                                       
    (shell-command "imagesnap -q ~/Desktop/emacs-snap.jpg")                             
    (insert (shell-command-to-string "jp2a --width=48 ~/Desktop/emacs-snap.jpg"))                                                                                                                                                               
    (shell-command "rm ~/Desktop/emacs-snap.jpg")                                       
)
```

This just takes a snap from the camera, converts to ascii, inserts it into my file, and places the cursor after.

Like I say, I would like it to keep looping, giving the appearance of a slow ascii video, until i tap a key to select the current 'frame'.

Is this even possible?

---

**EDIT**

This is my current code, which I'm fairly happy with. It loops 20 times, and you can choose the current image by cancelling (C-g). Things seem to go wrong when you do it a second time though.

```
(defun ascii-video-comment ()
 "Makes video comment, requires imagemagick, jp2a, imagesnap"
 (interactive)
 (cl-loop repeat 20 do
  (shell-command "imagesnap -q ~/Desktop/ascii-video-comment.jpg")
  (cua-set-mark)
  (insert (shell-command-to-string "jp2a --width=120 ~/Desktop/ascii-video-comment.jpg"))
  (shell-command "rm ~/Desktop/ascii-video-comment.jpg")
  (comment-region (mark) (point))
  (cua-set-mark)
  (pop-global-mark)
  (sit-for 0.1)
  (undo)
 )
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do a cat but now show output?

Comment: the commands are just examples. they could be anything

Comment: You can always pipe the output to `/dev/null` to prevent the output from going anywhere.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing this?  Put your commands in a shell script and code up some emacs-lisp to run it until required input is received.  When you are far enough along to come up with a request like this, you should be learning to do it yourself, IMO.

Comment: I have elaborated on my question

Comment: Why are you trying to chain commands in Emacs?  Shell scripts are designed for that.

Comment: maybe that would be better, but i don't want to have to rely on another file

Comment: i don't see the advantage of that

Comment: The advantage is it's possible to run your animation in the background while you continue editing your file.  Right now, you are foregrounding processes, and making Emacs unresponsive while your processes runs.

Comment: i see what you mean. is it possible to improve my code to make it do that?

Answer (score 2):

On your `EDIT` "final code": don't use interactive commands in a lisp program: you code becomes brittle and inefficient.
E.g., the doc string for `shell-command` (<kbd>C-h f shell-command RET</kbd>) explicitly states:

> In Elisp, you will often be better served by calling `call-process` or
>   `start-process` directly, since it offers more control and does not
>   impose the use of a shell (with its need to quote arguments)

Also, use `delete-file` instead of `(shell-command "rm ...")`.

Do not use `cua-set-mark`, `pop-global-mark`, and, especially, `undo` in programs.
Bind a variable instead:

```
(let ((beg (point)))
  (call-process "jp2a" nil t t "--width=120" "~/Desktop/ascii-video-comment.jpg")
  (comment-region beg (point))
  (sit-for 0.1)
  (delete-region beg (point)))
```

Comment: How about `shell-command-to-string`? Can that be replaced with call-process?

Answer (score 1):

<s>AFAIR, Emacs doesn't provide API to poll for pending events, so there are two options.</s> *UPD: disregard that, should've read the manual beforehand, Emacs does provide API to poll for pending events*:

```
(defun start-printing-messages-2 ()
  (interactive)
  (while (not (input-pending-p)) 
    (loop-body-function)
    (redisplay 'force)))
```

If you want a delay between command execution, there's `sit-for` for you:

```
(defun start-printing-messages-3 ()
  (interactive)
  (while (sit-for 0.05)
    (loop-body-function)))
```

If you want that delay to start counting from beginning of loop body rather than its end (if your loop body might take significant time), you need to set up full-fledged timer execution: you basically run a function in a timer and add a `post-command-hook` that will kill that timer:

```
(defvar loop-run-count 0)
(defvar loop-timer-object nil)

(defun loop-body-function ()
  (setq loop-run-count (1+ loop-run-count))
  (message "The function was run %s times" loop-run-count))

(defun stop-printing-messages ()
  (when loop-timer-object   
    (cancel-timer loop-timer-object)
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'stop-printing-messages)))

(defun start-printing-messages ()
  (interactive)
  (setq loop-run-count 0)
  ;; post-command-hook is added via timer too, because otherwise it
  ;; might get called right after this function completes and this
  ;; would kill the timer that didn't even start yet.
  ;; get killed right after creation.
  (run-with-timer
   0.01 nil (lambda ()
          (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'stop-printing-messages)))
  (setq loop-timer-object 
    (run-with-timer nil 0.01 'loop-body-function)))
```

Comment: I tried `(while (not (input-pending-p))` to loop, but my code set marks and undos etc, and I think this triggers the input-pending-p.. so it stops the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for input with `while-no-input` and `sit-for`.

For the use case you describe, `sit-for` is what you need.

Note that you should combine the two shell calls with `&&` or make a shell
script.

Here is a toy command that does what you need, but only flashing random numbers.

```
(defun flash-me ()
  "flash random number until you press a key"
  (interactive)
  (let ((beg (copy-marker (point)))
        (end (copy-marker (point) t)))
    (loop do (progn
               (delete-region beg end)
               (insert (shell-command-to-string "echo $RANDOM")))
          while (sit-for 1))
    (set-marker beg nil)
    (set-marker end nil)))
```